# store function creation error in mysql #1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried to create one function, ie if username exist, will return random number and character as a single string, but I tried below code, throwing syntax error like below, can u help to find the issue, I know that having issue in declaring string and returning string, but unable to find the issue. Thanks to the replies in advance

```
DELIMITER //
create function verifyEmail(userName varchar(25))
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    if EXISTS(select * from userdetails where name = userName)
    then
        SELECT @randomPass := select concat( char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1));
        return @randomPass;
    else
       return "not_exist";
    end if;
 end //
DELIMITER //
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select concat( char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(ra' at line 6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hooray, finally found answers.. This below code will help to solve the solution

```
DELIMITER //
create function verifyEmail(userName varchar(25))
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE randomPass VARCHAR(8);
    if EXISTS(select id from userdetails where name = userName)
    THEN        
       SET randomPass = concat( char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65),char(rand()*25+65));
       return randomPass;
    else
       return "not_exist";
    end if;
 end //
DELIMITER //
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing `)` on this line:

```
SELECT @randomPass := select concat( char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1);
```

should be

```
SELECT @randomPass := select concat( char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1), char(round(rand()*36)+1));
```

Comment: no here only I forget to put, but while trying I tried like that only sorry for the mistake